# Connect virtual subnets from two physical host

Tags: networking, routing, lxc, proxmox

I have proxmox 4 based on debian 8 on two hosts A and B. Both have two NICs. One NIC from each host is connected via a Crossover cable.

```
Host A:
eth0: public IP
eth1: 10.0.0.2/24
vmbr1: 10.0.0.1/24

Host B:
eth0: public IP
eth1: 10.0.1.2/24
vmbr1: 10.0.1.1/24
```

On vmbr1 there is a container attached on each host with 10.0.x.10. I gonna denote it like this:

```
Host A:
veth100i1@if12: 10.0.0.10/24 (IP only visible inside container on eth0)

Host B:
veth100if1@if30: 10.0.1.10/24 (IP only visible inside container on eth0)
```

Routing table host A:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
X.X.X.0         X.X.X.X         255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 eth0
X.X.X.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr1
10.0.1.0        10.0.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Routing table host B:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         Y.Y.Y.Y         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
Y.Y.Y.0         Y.Y.Y.Y         255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 eth0
Y.Y.Y.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
10.0.0.0        10.0.1.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
10.0.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr1
```

From Host A I can ping to

- its container on 10.0.0.10
- Host's B eth1 on 10.0.1.2
- Host's B vmbr1 on 10.0.1.1
- but not to Host's B container on 10.0.1.10

From Host B I can ping to

- its container on 10.0.1.10
- Host's A eth1 on 10.0.0.2
- Host's A vmbr1 on 10.0.1.1
- but not on Host's A container on 10.0.0.10

When I try to ping 10.0.1.10 from Host A on container in Host B I can see the following on eth1 of Host B:

```
tcpdump -nni eth1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:42:48.567438 ARP, Request who-has 10.0.1.10 tell 10.0.0.2, length 46
```

On vmbr1 of host B, tcpdump shows nothing.

How to route the packets into the containers of the other host's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the eth1 interfaces to addresses in a third subnet like 10.0.3.0/24. You will likely need to add forwarding as listed below as well.

Or try proxying the ARP request for the available servers.  You can enable this manually with a command like.

```
systctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.proxy_arp=1
```

Once you have it working you can make it stick over reboots by adding a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` containing a line like:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.proxy_arp = 1
```

You may also need to enable enable forwarding with either of these settings:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.forwarding = 1
```

An alternative approach would be to include eth1 in the vmbr1 definition.  This may be a better approach in the long run.

Comment: systctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.proxy_arp=1 did the trick. Forwarding was already enabled. Thanks!